# Typescript error when dispatching action created by createAsyncThunk from saga

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-saga, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

Example:

```js
/* actions.ts */
export const getTeacherChats = createAsyncThunk(
  'messenger/chats',
  async (params, thunkAPI) => {
    const response = await messenger.getTeacherChats()
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.data
    }
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(response.error.text)
  }
)
```

```js
/* saga.ts */
function* teacherChatsWatcher() {
/* Error on the next line: 
    Argument of type 'AsyncThunkAction<TMessengerChatsResponse, void, {}>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Action<any>'.
      Property 'type' is missing in type 'AsyncThunkAction<TMessengerChatsResponse, void, {}>' but required in type 'Action<any>'. */
    yield put(getTeacherChats())
}

export default function* messengerSaga() {
  yield fork(teacherChatsWatcher)
}
```

Is it possible to dispatch thunk action by put effect from redux-saga?
What should I do to dispatch this action from saga?

**UPD:** Action is dispatched in this way and it works correct, but TS error still exists.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, unfortunately, looking at the definition of `put` in https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/24e9a68d621fd2a57a29b3b80e4b54ecb22fa593/packages/core/types/effects.d.ts#L367, it just doesn't take any other possible action types into account.

You can probably make do by augmenting those types:

```
declare module "@redux-saga/core/types/effects" {
  // this is the original definition
  export function put<A extends Action>(action: A): PutEffect<A>;
  // let's add an overload
  export function put<A extends ThunkAction>(action: A): PutEffect<A>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The original answer was correct, but `redux-saga` v1.2.4 (pending release) should include types for thunk actions. https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/9c59ac93ec4389d6a1e98e46fc3cddb98523e589/packages/core/types/effects.d.ts#L382

Excerpt:

```js
/**
 * Creates an Effect description that instructs the middleware to dispatch an
 * action to the Store. This effect is non-blocking, any errors that are
 * thrown downstream (e.g. in a reducer) will bubble back into the saga.
 *
 * @param action [see Redux `dispatch` documentation for complete info](https://redux.js.org/api/store#dispatchaction)
 */
export function put<A extends Action>(action: A): PutEffect<A>
export function put<ReturnType = any, State = any, ExtraThunkArg = any, BasicAction extends Action = Action>(
  action: ThunkAction<ReturnType, State, ExtraThunkArg, BasicAction>,
): PutEffect<BasicAction>
```

The change is not mentioned in the CHANGELOG, but it is visible from the release diff. https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/compare/redux-saga%401.2.3...main

A simple example [modified from the tests](https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/blob/9c59ac93ec4389d6a1e98e46fc3cddb98523e589/packages/core/types/effects.test.ts#L96):

```js
  const thunkActionCreator = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'thunk-action' })

    return 42
  }

  yield put(thunkActionCreator())
```

Comment: The above type fix was included in `1.3.0`, see https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga/pull/2386